# sectsty interferes with documentclass scrreprt Chapter Titles!

Tags: chapters, sectsty, scrreprt

I've created a minimal example that visualizes the problem:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix = true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello world!}
\end{document}
```

As you'll see, the chapter title is displayed something like this:

**Chapter 1Hello world!**

Only when the `sectsty` package is commented out, the chapter title is displayed correctly:

**Chapter 1**

**Hello world!**

Is there an easy fix to this?

Updated minimal example, to test a possible solution without using sectsty:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix = true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red!20}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello world!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `sectsty` is for standard document classes. It is incompatible with the advanced KOMA-script interface.

Comment: Would it be an option not to use `sectsty` when you use a KOMA class? `sectsty` is from 1999 and the documentation notes that for simple tasks KOMA has its own interfaces that are probably easier to use it goes on to say that there might be uses for `secsty` with KOMA classes. But that was almost twenty years ago and KOMA development has progressed a lot over since then, so it is not impossible that something broke `sectsty`. Especially since KOMA has many customisation features on its own. What do you use `sectsty` for?

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. I'm only using `sectsty` to change the color of the chapter and section titles, through: `\chapterfont{\color{chaptercolor}}`, so I think there should be a way to do this without `sectsty`. 

Comment: `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red!20}}`

Comment: Now, this is already looking quite good! The only problem now is that, in the Table of Contents, the page number of the chapters are displayed in that color. They should be black.

Comment: Post a minimal working example

Comment: Trying to do it. Funny enough, your command is working in my thesis template, but my updated minimal example (cf. initial post) doesn't compile.

Comment: `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{red!20}}`?

Comment: Ok, so the `xcolor` package was necessary. Thanks! Now, the specification for my report is that the ToC is in black.

Comment: Try `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{red!20}}` or if that does not work as expected (naturally the heading of the TOC will be coloured since it is at chapter level) `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red!20}}`/\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{red!20}}` *after* `\tableofcontents` (there are differences for `\section` and many other document elements between the approaches).

Comment: That was my thought exactly. I put `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red!20}}` just before the body text begins, and now it's flawless. ❤

Thanks @moewe and @Johannes_B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it all possible I would avoid using `sectsty` together with KOMA classes. `sectsty` was written in 1999 and the KOMA classes have received multiple updates over the last twenty years or so. It is not surprising that some features of `sectsty` would interfere with KOMA given that it was mainly written for the standard classes. The KOMA classes have extensive options to change the output of sectioning commands so that `sectsty` should not be needed in most cases.

In this case it turns out that

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red!20}}
```

before the beginning of the body text/main matter gives the desired result.

---

As mentioned by [@esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43317/esdd) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436837/sectsty-interferes-with-documentclass-scrreprt-chapter-titles/436842?noredirect=1#comment1096025_436842) it might be slightly nicer to say

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red!20}}
\BeforeTOCHead{\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor}}
```

in the preamble to colour all sectioning elements but exempt the TOC and other "list of ..."s controlled by KOMA's `tocbasic`.

Comment: This can also be done in the preamble if  `\BeforeTOCHead{\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor}}` is added. Then `disposition` uses `\normalcolor` in TOC, LOF, LOT and other lists under the control of package `tocbasic`.

Comment: @esdd Thank you very much for that hint. I have taken the liberty of adding it to the answer.